# wordpress wp_insert_post is taking too long

Tags: php, database, wordpress

I'm using a simple php file to post to my wordpress, i have around 900posts so far, yet i noticed that time it takes to post is getting so long ! that some times it even runs out (30sec+) ! here is code i use.

```
 <?php
  require_once('./../wp-blog-header.php');
  require_once('./simple_html_dom.php');
  require_once('./../wp-admin/includes/taxonomy.php');

function postit($category,$date,$title,$content,$keys){
$cat=wp_create_category($category);
$post = array(
  'comment_status' => 'open',// 'closed' means no comments.
  'ping_status'    => 'open', // 'closed' means pingbacks or trackbacks turned off
  'post_author'    => '1', //The user ID number of the author.
  'post_category'  => array($cat), //post_category no longer exists, try wp_set_post_terms() for setting a post's categories
  'post_content'   => $content, //The full text of the post.
  'post_date'      => date('Y-m-d H:i:s',strtotime($date)), //The time post was made.
  'post_date_gmt'  => date('Y-m-d H:i:s',strtotime($date)), //The time post was made, in GMT.
  'post_status'    => 'publish', //Set the status of the new post.
  'post_title'     => $title, //The title of your post.
  'post_type'      => 'post', //You may want to insert a regular post, page, link, a menu item or some custom post type
  'tags_input'     => $keys,//For tags.
  'post_content_filtered' => '1',
  'filter' => '1'
);

remove_filter('content_save_pre', 'wp_filter_post_kses');
remove_filter('content_filtered_save_pre', 'wp_filter_post_kses');
$r=wp_insert_post( $post ,$wp_error);
add_filter('content_save_pre', 'wp_filter_post_kses');
add_filter('content_filtered_save_pre', 'wp_filter_post_kses');
return $r;
}
```

when i ran this in profiler,

wp_create_category runs 0.01 sec. and rest of code 0.8 sec while the part of removing filter and wp_insert_post takes the rest of excution time..

any one have a suggestion to optimize this ?

Comment: does this still happen on the dashboard as well?

Comment: @RobertLee yes same for dashboard

Comment: have you tried to optimize your database?  there are manual queries you can do but this one is a bit easier to use http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/tentblogger-optimize-wordpress-database-plugin/

Comment: How are you queuing up the scripts to execute? Maybe you can space them out by 0.1s between runs.

Answer (score 2):

found solution. it was **one of my plugins** that made this delay. once i disabled all plugins the delay was goan !.

i think some plugins added a filter/hook to wp_new_post and that hook caused this delay problem.

for future googlers. **just disable all your plugins** and try to post, if problem is goan then start to enable them one by one untill you find the plugin that is causing this problem.

thanks all for comments and help

Comment: Thanks that helped me a lot, for me it was the plugin "WP-Mail-SMTP". I've hooked an email sending on "wp_insert_post" hook, and the smtp was missconfigured. Disabling it has solved my issue